# How to check phone service state in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i am trying to check the service state of phone

using  Service state: IN_SERVICE 
if the phone is IN_SERVICE generate a Toast phone is in service if its not then generate a Toast phone is not in service
 im trying this code

```
public class MyphoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
{
     switch (state) {  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:   
            break;  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
           sendemail(); 
            break;  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
        default:  
            break;  
        }  
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);  
    }
}
```

not able to get the  Service state: IN_SERVICE    Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager telMng = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
telMng.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onServiceStateChanged (ServiceState serviceState) {
        super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
        String phonestate;

        switch(serviceState.getState()) {
            case ServiceState.STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY: 
                phonestate ="STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY";
                break;
            case ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE: 
                phonestate ="STATE_IN_SERVICE";
                break;
            case ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE: 
                phonestate ="STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE"; 
                break;
            case ServiceState.STATE_POWER_OFF: 
                phonestate ="STATE_POWER_OFF"; 
                break;
            default:
                phonestate = "Unknown";
                break;
        }   
    } 
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
```

Comment: i dont need to getCallState()  but i want to  get the ServiceState() i read it here                                                       http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html#STATE_IN_SERVICE                               Plz help me or give me some link to do it

Comment: thanks for giving me response i tried above code but its giving error PhoneStateListener cannot be resolved to a variable                 i dont know what should do plz guide me.       thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you didn't forget a ')' or ';'?

Comment: thanks for reply        i m using your code when i m removing this comma                                                               }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);                         } PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);       but still is showing some error like   Syntax error on token "PhoneStateListener", delete this token                                                                   plz help me  thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you sir its working i checked it correctly. thanks again from my bottom of heart...

Comment: Can we get Phone State of someone's simcard while calling it?. Means IF i have 10 mobile numbers. i want to know phone numbers are active or not.so can we get status for other's phone by calling on that numbers one by one?

Comment: This work on one-sims devices. What about dual-sim phones? How I can create PhoneStateListener for second sim-card?

Comment: @TapaSave You just have to create a `TelephonyManager` for the second SIM card, and listen to it with another `PhoneStateListener`. See [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) doc for how to create one for specific subscription (i.e. one matching one of the SIMs), this works on API 24+