# How to detect emergency call only in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, call

Is there a way to detect if the phone, at the call try moment, can only make emergency calls (using Xamarin)?

Answer (score 0):

This is something platform specific. Unfortunaelty I don't know any plugin for this, so you have to use the native API in Xamarin.

On Android it is the `TelephonyManager` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355706/1489968 It's Java, but can be easily translated to C#:

```cs
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var telMng = (TelephonyManager) GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
        var myPhoneStateListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        myPhoneStateListener.ServiceStateChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", e);
        telMng.Listen(myPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListenerFlags.ServiceState);
    }
}

public class MyPhoneStateListener : PhoneStateListener
{
    public event EventHandler<ServiceState> ServiceStateChanged;
    public override void OnServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState)
    {
        base.OnServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
        ServiceStateChanged?.Invoke(this, serviceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS: Not sure if that information is available, never have seen it exposed via the SDK... (maybe add iOS tag to this question, or ask an `iOS only` question, answer might be in ObjC/Swift but you can translate it)

On Android: The info you are looking for is contained within the `ServiceState` of the phone:

```
var callState = new ServiceState ();
switch (callState.State) {
case PhoneState.InService:
    {
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("tel:555-2368"); // Jim Rockford's number ;-)
        var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionDial, uri);
        StartActivity (intent);
        break;
    }
case PhoneState.EmergencyOnly:
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, "Emergency Calls Only", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        break;
    }
case PhoneState.OutOfService:
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, "Out of Service", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        break;
    }
case PhoneState.PowerOff:
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, "Cell/Modem Power Off", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        break;
    }
default:
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, "Should never be shown on a real device", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

For testing on the emulator, you can set the state to `denied` via the `adb` shell:

```
voice denied
data denied
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html